# Translate vertices from space to another

Tags: math, vector, matrix, rotation

I have 3D-vertices that are read from a model which up-direction is defined by unit-vector **u**. I need to translate all those vertex points to another space which up-direction is defined by unit-vector **v**.

I know that if original up direction is (0,1,0) and target is (1,0,0), I can use rotation matrix somewhat like this for all the points:

```
x' = x*cos(-90) - y*sin(-90) = y
y' = x*sin(-90) + y*cos(-90) = -x
z' = z

where -90 is the angle from (0,1,0) to (1,0,0).
```

...but so far my tryouts to generalize this approach for the case mentioned in the begining have proven futile.

Any suggestions how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To generalize this, you can use an angle/axis rotation specification where the rotation angle is given by θ = cos<sup>-1</sup>(**u**∙**v** / |**u**||**v**|) and the axis is given by **r** = (**u**/|**u**|)×(**v**/|**v**|) where ∙ is the [dot product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product), × is the [cross product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product) and | | is the [Euclidean (L2) norm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_%28mathematics%29#Euclidean_norm).  You can either use a [quaternion formulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternions_and_spatial_rotation) or a [rotation matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#Rotation_matrix_from_axis_and_angle) to actually generate the linear transformation.

**Why this works**: The dot product of two unit length vectors is the cosine of the angle between those two vectors.  The cross product of two unit length 3D vectors is one of two unit length 3D vectors orthogonal (perpendicular) to the other two.  The two vectors differ only in their sign such that **u**×**v** = -**v**×**u**, so the formulation above may have a sign issue if I got the order wrong in the cross product.

Comment: And there seems to be everything I need. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

if your up vector is [ Ux, Uy, 0 ]:

```
x' = Ux*x + Uy*y
y' = Uy*x - Ux*y 
z' = z
```

You could generalize this better and cover all arbitrary angles if you used Matrices. For example:

```
[ Ux, Uy, 0,
  Uy,-Ux, 0,
  0,  0,  1  ]
```

and simply multiply the vector by the matrix.

Or use three vectors for your orientation Up Right and Back then your matrix is:

```
[ Rx, Ry, Rz,
  Ux, Uy, Uz, 
  Bx, By, Bz ]
```

and multiplying the vector by the matrix will be like this:

```
x' = x*Rx + y*Ry + z*Rz
y' = x*Ux + y*Uy + z*Uz    
z' = x*Bx + y*By + z*Bz
```

In your particular case you have R=[1,0,0], U=[0,1,0] and B=[0,0,1] which you then reoriented to R=[0,-1,0], U=[1,0,0] and B=[0,0,1]

Comment: I'm looking for generalization: Point p(x0, y0, z0) is defined in space which up vector is U(x1, y1, z1) and I need to translate the point to the space which up vector is V(x2, y2, z2).